# Is Probabilistic Perspective a nice method to predict clients' preference trends commercially？

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, probabilistic-programming

There is a company, it provides 200 products for its 8000 customers. The average number of customers purchased products is 10. Some big customers may buy 20 or more products.

The mainstream products are hot, now the company wants to enlarge its market with **AI**.

This is the question, the company does not provide clients' data to you. You have to google something to replace.

My general solution: If customer A purchases a, b, c, d and e products, customer B purchases a, b, c and d products. If I promote e to customer B, I can do it easily.

Seriously, in my opinion, it is a 8000*n dataset, and I need to do a data clustering at first, heatmap or dendrogram. Then using the predictive modelling, p(e|a，b，c，d) for each cluster. Is is ok?

**You can ignore following sentences.**

Hi! I am a bachelor of Information System in the final semester, join a project(a new project aims to let different industries students cooperate), have a business mentor who knows nothing about computer science and business teammates who do not know what is R, what is SPSS.

Our project sounds nice, we have a nice talk with client, everything seems nice. We start to do the timeline now.

Comment: Market Basket Analysis can help you how to combine the products in order to maximize the purchases. It's a better tecnique for you because the order of the purchase of the products are considered, and in a cluster analysis it's not. Take a look in the reference from IBM SPSS Modeler (here they call association rule's node - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_17.0.0/components/gsar/gsar_model_options.html )

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, however in doing so you are restricting yourself, since you might also learn something from a customer that bought (a, b, d, f, e).

The general  problem you want to solve is recommendation. The state-of-the-art methods usually employ [matrix factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_factorization_(recommender_systems)) for this.

[Here is a nice library for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recosystem/vignettes/introduction.html). Similar libraries should be available for SPSS.